# Join with max time in EF Core C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

```
SELECT *
FROM Jobs j
WHERE j.InsertTime = (SELECT MAX(InsertTime) FROM Jobs)
```

How convert this SQL script to C# query?

I try this but not worked:

```
from j in _dbContext.Jobs
group j by j.InsertTime into g
select g.OrderByDescending(s=>s.InsertTime).First() into item
select item;
```

Sample data:

```
title | insertTime
------|-------------
  AA  | 2022-05-03
  B   | 2022-05-03
  A   | 2022-05-04
  B   | 2022-05-04
```

Result:

```
title | insertTime
------|-------------
  A   | 2022-05-04
  B   | 2022-05-04
```

Comment: Which EF Core version?

Comment: What's the precision of `InsertTime`? Do you even get more than one? I.e. can't you just as well order by `InsertTime` (desc) and take the first?

Comment: @GertArnold I have a list of jobs that are inserted together. And according to the last date, I want to display the list.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Ver5.0.4

Comment: In actual SQL you don't need the join, you can use `TOP (1) WITH TIES` but this is not available in Linq as far as I know

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query:

```cs
var query =  
    from d in _dbContext.Jobs.Select(d => new { d.Title }).Distinct()
    from j in _dbContext.Jobs
        .Wehere(j => j.Ttle == d.Ttle)
        .OrderByDescending(j => j.InsertTime)
        .Take(1)
    select j;
```